# Google Analytic in Android App not working

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics, mobile-app-tracker

Its my First time trying to integrate "Google Analytic" to y Android App.
I followed this Tutorial

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

But its not working. Whats the Problem. May be I haven't written the Complete Code. May Be I am missing something. I don't know the exact Procedure.

What I did is,

- 1st, Added Permission in My Manifest File as follows

  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`
- 2nd, added dependency in project's gradle file

**In Top Level**

classpath `com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1`

**In Project Level**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'
```

- 3rd, I Created and Downloaded a "Configuration File" as mentioned in the above Link, and placed that file in "app" folder in my Project Directory
- 4th, I created a class named "AnalyticsApplication" which extends "Application" with the following code

  ```
  public class AnalyticsApplication extends Application{

  private Tracker mTracker;

    synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
  if (mTracker == null) {
      GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
      // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
      mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
  }
  return mTracker;
  }
  }
  ```

5th, in onCreate method of any one Activity which I want to Track, I wrote the following Code

```
AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
```

Then, in onResume method of that Activity, I wrote the following Code

```
Log.i(LOG_TKT,"Setting screen name: " + "MainActivity Screen");
    mTracker.setScreenName("Image~" + "MainActivity Screen");
    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .setCategory("Action")
            .setAction("Share")
            .build());
```

That's it. Please Help where I went wrong. OR What is the Correct Method of doing it ?

Comment: how do you know its not working? did you check the real-time reports on the Google Analytics website?     When did you create the Google Analytics application account?

Comment: Hey @DaImTo I Create my Google Analytics account, because of this, I was able to create and download the Configuration File as mentioned in the Link. I am checking the Google Analytic Real Time Page, but its showing 0

Comment: How long ago did you create the Google Analytics account?  It takes 48 - 72 hours for it to start showing data.

Comment: @DaImTo okie, But it should show the Real time instantly. I mean if I open my App, I should be able to see 1 Device live in my Real Time Google Analytic Page. I am not able to see this Real Time stats. And Secondly I think its updating after 48 hours but when I see the country wise, its showing me wrong countries, and my country is 0

Comment: Actually @DaImTo I dont know exactly how to check this whole process, that,  whether its correctly monitoring my app or not ? whether its working or not ?

Comment: If its a brand new created Google analytics account you will need to wait a few days for it to start showing data.   If your code is correct it should show data in the real-time reports instantly.  data will appear in the standard reports 24 hours after that.

Comment: @DaImTo yes you r right. This is the problem. I want to know whether my written code is correct or not ? Could you please give my any link or tutorial which you have tested as 100% working ?

Comment: sorry I am not an android developer if you followed Googles tutorial it "should" work.  That tutorial is very reliable to my knowledge it works.  Wait the few days and wait for an android developer to double check your code.  But 90% of the time the issue is that the account is to new to display data.   If you are lucky it will show up tomorrow.

Comment: Have you added android:name=".AnalyticsApplication" into your application tag in the manifest?

Comment: @JesusS Yes `android:name=".AnalyticsApplication"` inside <application> tag in Manifest File